# Google Sheets: How can I substitute or replace a text with a multiplication sign (operator sign)?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

What I am trying to accomplish is.... to  substitute or replace the text string "X" with a multiplication sign (operator sign)  as the formula is provided below:
=SUBSTITUTE(C10, ""X"", *)

The data in Cell c10 looks like this.....(25X06).  I would like to multiply those two-numbers"

Comment: Does C10 actually have opening and closing parenthesis, or is that just how you wrote it in your post? That is, does C10 contain (25X06) or 25X06? And is your end goal to process just C10, or is it to process a number of rows in this format? The answers to these questions are necessary before knowing how best to offer a concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

```
=("="&SUBSTITUTE(B11,"X","*"))
```

but this give you a formula as string, not the result! To get the result

```
=PRODUCT(arrayformula(value(substitute(substitute(split(B11,"X"),"(",""),")",""))))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your suggestion?   Just to clarify.  I would like to substitute a string text whch is "X"...    and to replace it with a multiplication sign (operator) so that I can multiply the two sets of numbers in cell C10.

Comment: I fully understand what you need. But if you only replace X with * you will get an inoperative formula, just text that looks like a formula! look here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifJ1KHqqQRq7ZD3A-y0JEsrm5wKUB5CQCMHPnfs77S0/edit?usp=sharing